# getting number of Pencils class of type Pencils

Tags: java

So I am making a Boxes class that has an arraylist of Pencils of the Pencils class. And my Pencils class has an arraylist of strings for germs. Pencils have a specific unique number for marking purposes and a brandname. How do I get the specific unique number of each pencil of type Pencils? Basically I'm wondering how to write the getPencilNumber() method. Please answer it with basic java. Here is some general info. Assume the fields are already there. I want to do something like

In the Boxes class

```
ArrayList<Pencil> Storage
private Flight getFlight(int num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size(); i++){
        if(Store.get(i).getPencilNumber() == num)
            return Storage.get(i);
        }
    return null; 
}
```

In the Pencils class

```
public Pencils(int number, String brandName){
    this.number=number;
    this.brandName=brandName;
    Germs=new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: You should have `public int getNumber() {return this.number;}` in `Pencils` calss, and you just need to call that.

Comment: Your method `getFlight` returns `Flight`, but you have a return statement returning something from `storage` which is list of `Pencil`. Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `pencil.getPencilNumber()`. So in your `Pencil` class you should have:

```
public int getPencilNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

Then you will get the number. *note*: this method should be called `getNumber()` to follow java conventions.

Or, if `number` is `public` you can do:

```
pencil.number
```

But generally you don't want class variables to be public. You should have them private and access them via getters and setters.